# A mathematical derivation of $E = hv$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, photons, frequency

Though at its origin, the formula for the energy of a photon $\varepsilon=hv$ is a postulate, is there a way of proving this formula mathematically, with consideration of Newtonian mechanics and the fact that light is an electromagnetic wave? I understand this can be a problematic approach since the formula and its implications are of a quantum mechanical nature. However, this formula is considered to have played a big part in the birth of quantum mechanics, and in a since, predates quantum mechanics, So it seems natural that it could be derived "classically".

Here's my failed approach:

Assuming the electric field of an electromagnetic wave is of the form:

$$E=E_0 sin(\frac{2 \pi}{\lambda}x-2\pi vt)$$

Where $v$ is the frequency of the wave, and $\lambda$ is the wavelength.

Say the electromagnetic field interacts with some particle with unit mass and charge, located at point $x=0$ (for simplicity), we can get the particle's equation of motion along the axis of the electric field (y axis):

$$\ddot{y}=E$$
$$\ddot{y}=E_0 sin(-2\pi v t)$$

Integrating with respect to time we get the velocity:

$$\dot{y}=\frac{E_0}{2\pi v} cos(2\pi v t)$$

For simplicity, we'll take the maximum kinetic energy the electric field inflicts on the particle to be the energy of the electromagnetic wave:
$$\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}\dot{y}_{max}^2$$
$$\dot{y}_{max}=\frac{E_0}{2\pi v}$$
$$\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{E_0}{2\pi v})^2$$
$$\varepsilon=\frac{E_0^2}{8\pi ^2} \frac{1}{v^2}$$

We therefore get that:
$$\varepsilon \propto \frac{1}{v^2}$$
Which is obviously not the expected energy - frequency relation. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't derived it classically. It is a postulate of the quantum theory.

Comment: All relations containing $h$ are purely quantum-mechanical.
They can't be derived from classical mechanics.

Comment: To me, this seems to be off topic. It seems like a weird kind of "check my work" question. Your title seems to imply that you are performing a "mathematical derivation of h\nu." But the derivation is completely confused. I don't think there is much other insight I can bring other than saying this approach is completely wrong.

Comment: You can use the action angle variables in Hamilton jacobi equation. It has some close resemblance with old quantum mechanics

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> $E=h\nu$ is a postulate

You don't derive postulates, or they would not be called postulates.  They're base assumptions required to get results that match experiments (usually).

> this formula is considered to have played a big part in the birth of quantum mechanics, and in a since, predates quantum mechanics, So it seems natural that it could be derived "classically".

That's faulty logic.

It predates quantum theory only in the sense that it was a step on the path to discovering quantum theory.

It is a step *beyond* classical physics not part of classical physics.

So it would *not* be natural to derive it from classical physics.  It's simply something added to the body of theories that moves things beyond classical physics.